2 Sagdah sauf in a namaz
Can I do 2 sagdah sauf in a single fard like if I did the first sagdah sauf and did it wrong so can I make another sagdah sauf another time and if not so then I have did 2 sagdah sauf in total of 6 prayers I don't correctly remember it was fagar or Zohar or isha so what I have to do in that case please guide me
